# Possible to list members of a network bridge?

Tags: linux, networking, centos, bridge

When installing KVM on Fedora or CentOS it creates `virbr0`, but I can't see anywhere that `en0` is part of the bridge.

**Question**

Is there are a command to see the members of a network bridge?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The command which handles bridging in Linux is brctl.

The command you are most likely looking for is

```
   brctl show
```

The bridge name is, of-course on the left, and all the interfaces connected to that bridge will be listed - one per line - on the right in the "interfaces" column.

You may also specify a specific bridge with a command like

```
  brctl show virbr0
```

Comment: This answer should no longer be the accepted one. bridge-utils is depreciated. See A.B's answer below.

Answer (score 29):

Alternatively, there's a more recent command provided by [*iproute2*](https://wiki.linuxfoundation.org/networking/iproute2), used together with [`ip link`](https://manpages.debian.org/iproute2/ip-link.8) to manage bridges: the [`bridge`](https://manpages.debian.org/iproute2/bridge.8) command. It can handle new bridge features not available through `brctl` (like VLAN filtering (to enable vlan handling directly by the bridge), port isolation (similar to PVLAN) or hairpin).

Modern syntax to display bridges would be:

```
ip link show type bridge
```

or looking for/by bridge ports:

```
bridge link show
```

or

```
bridge link show dev <interface>
```

To show only the ports of a given bridge requires again the `ip link` command:

```
ip link show master <bridgename>
```

The results might be a bit less pretty, but can provide more informations. Newer versions of *iproute2* provide the `bridge` command with a JSON output (same for `ip link show`: try for example `ip -details -pretty -json link show type bridge`).

Answer (score 4):

The best way I feel is to list the contents in this directory :

```
/sys/class/net/<bridge-name>/brif
```

This helps you parse the output. brctl show and other commands will be difficult to parse